# Should I include my converted GPA/final semester GPA on my CV?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, gpa

I'm applying to graduate school and I'm contacting potential supervisors, as advised by the universities I'm applying to.

My GPA is 16.33/20. When I convert it to the 4.0 scale,according to WES, my overall GPA, GPA in the final 2 years, the final year and the final semester are 3.41, 3.34, 3.4 and 4.0 respectively.

Does 3.41 look better than 16.33? As I want to make a good first impression, should I include my final semester GPA or does it simply highlight my poor performance in the previous semester?

Comment: Why would you include final year/semester GPA anyway? The only GPA subset I've ever heard of is major GPA.

Answer (score 4):

Provide a copy of the original transcript(s) detailing all the grades.

Any university will convert the values according to their "rules" and evaluate your application as necessary.

Comment: Of course I will do that. This is only for the purpose of a good first impression when contacting supervisors. I just want to know which one looks better.

Comment: As a first impression, stick to your strengths, but also stick to things that display your ability to conduct research. GPA doesn't do this, so why lead with that? Just send a transcript along.

Answer (score 1):

Don't "convert" your GPA. Just leave it as is. For one thing, the most useful conversion from x/20 to y/4 is not necessarily as simple as dividing x by 5. I've been on grad admissions committees (in the U.S., for math) for many years, and our standard is to just look at the transcript, and to ignore student-reported stuff except as a place-holder.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't describe the smaller time periods within the CV.  If you want to emphasize an improvement trend, do it within your essay.  Just list the 4 year average on the resume.

Yes, convert it to 4.0 scale.  It is the stereotypical standard.  Leaving it as 16.3/20 is a pain, forcing most readers to convert themselves.

Comment: It's not clear whether/that the conversion is simply linear...